# Postfix can only send mail to my own e-mail address

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, gmail

So, my Postfix e-mail server can only send e-mails to my personal e-mail. Let's call it someone@gmail.com. When I try to send an e-mail to person2@gmail.com, that gets rejected:

```
<***@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]
said: 550-5.7.1 [2001:19f0:6c01:295:5400:ff:fe50:e9e1] Our system has
detected that 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines
regarding PTR 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550
5.7.1 . v2si15963925wrd.12 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
Final-Recipient: rfc822; ***@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;***@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [2001:19f0:6c01:295:5400:ff:fe50:e9e1] Our
    system has detected that 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending
    guidelines regarding PTR 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please
    review 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more
    information 550 5.7.1 . v2si15963925wrd.12 - gsmtp
```

Which is strange, as both of the e-mail addresses are from Gmail. It is complaining about my PTR records, but I believe those are set up correctly.

Output of: `dig -x <My IP> +short`

```
<My IP>.example.com.
```

Which contains my hostname, `example.com`.
When I do a lookup on my hostname, I get:

```
dig example.com +short
<My IP>
```

The IP returned matches the IP I did the original lookup on.

Here are my DNS records for `example.com`:

```
Name = ""; Type = A; TTL = 14440; Target = <My IP>
Name = "WWW"; Type = A; TTL = 14440; Target = <My IP>
Name = "<My IP>"; Type = A; TTL = 14440; Target = <My IP>
Name = ""; Type = MX; TTL = 14440; Target = "example.com"; Priority = 10
Name = ""; Type = TXT;TTL = 14440; Target = "v=spf1 mx a ~all"
```

Output from `telnet` when sending mail:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
EHLO example.com
250-example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
MAIL FROM: test@example.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: someone@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A722E40348
```

And the e-mail shows up perfectly in my inbox (not in the spam folder).
Sending a mail to my other Gmail address:

```
MAIL FROM: test@example.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: person2@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 23E8D40348
```

Nothing shows up. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a really obvious question, but do you have a PTR record set for the IPv6 address your server is sending from?

The records you've posted do not contain any information regarding AAAA - so I cannot tell.

You might try limiting postfix to send only from the legacy IPv4 only. If your mails go through you have triaged the issue to the IPv6-transport being the culprit. If the error persists you can dig deeper.

Comment: My IPv6 address has the same PTR record as my IPv4 address.